# GCC is showing "pow" as an undefined directory

Tags: gcc

I'm using Code::Blocks on Ubuntu 18.04. However, I'm unable to compile the following program successfully.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    char binary[65];
    int len, decimal, power, i;
    printf("Enter the binary number: ");
    scanf("%s", binary);
    decimal = 0;
    len = strlen(binary);
    power = len - 1;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        decimal += pow(2, power);
        power--;
    }
    printf("Decimal value is %d\n", decimal);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <math.h>` only imports the *declaration* of `pow`; for its *definition* you also need to link the `libm` library by adding `-lm` to your linker command

Comment: I don’t know how to do that be cause i am noob

Comment: Well yeah... but that's really a question about Code::Blocks not about Ubuntu - [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1297268/178692) shows how to do it with the standard Ubuntu compiler `gcc`. That's the tradefoff with IDEs - they make complex things simple, but make simple things (like adding a library) complicated.

Comment: But it not occurring only in codeblocks but also clion,geny etc ide

Comment: Each tool will have its own way of doing that - in geany for example you can go to **Build** -> **Set Build Commands** and add `-lm` to the **Build** command. Code::Blocks likely has something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Like so if your program name is main.c and your compiler is gcc. You open the terminal and write `gcc main.c -o main -lm`